# OpenJDK doesn't get recognized even though the system variables are set

Tags: java, minecraft, openjdk

Basically what the title says.

The error is "This application requires a Java Runtime Environment 1.6.0"

The application I am trying to run is the FTP legacy launcher which is a Minecraft launcher.

I am on Windows 10.

Edit: Version is 12.0.1.

Comment: What version of the OpenJDK do you have installed?  The error indicates you do NOT have Java 6 installed.  Instead of submitting a comment, please edit your question, to include the vital information required to answer your question.

Comment: 12.0.1 is the version.

Comment: Java 12 SE isn't compatiable with the tool you are trying to run.

Answer (score 0):

> The application I am trying to run is the FTP legacy launcher which is a Minecraft launcher.  When I launch the application, I receive an error that states, "This application requires a Java Runtime Environment 1.6.0".

You have installed Java 12 SE.  You need to install [Java 6 SE](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase6-419409.html) instead.  A compatible version of OpenJDK does not exist for the version of Java the tool requires.  OpenJDK 9+ are the only versions that exist for Windows.

Source: [How to download and install prebuilt OpenJDK packages](http://openjdk.java.net/install/index.html)

Comment: I suggest you find a compatiable tool that supports a more modern version of Java.  While Java is indeed backward compatible, this particular tool was compiled specifically, only to support Java 1.6 (based on the error message you received).  OpenJDK when properly installed updates the PATH system variable  and allows any compatiable Java application to run.